# Converting a for loop into one-liner to compare performance

Tags: python

I'm comparing time it takes to execute two blocks of code:

```
import time

start = time.time()
a = []
for x in range(10000):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        a.append(x)

finish = time.time()
print('stopwatch: ', finish - start)
```

but when I turn the for loop into one-liner I get syntax error:

```
start = time.time()
a = [x if x % 2 == 0 for x in range(10000)]
finish = time.time()
print('stopwatch: ', finish - start)
```

How would I write one-liner for the for loop above ?

Comment: When asking about errors, please include the full and complete error output in the question.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement is misplaced.

```py
start = time.time()
a = [x for x in range(10000) if x % 2 == 0 ]
finish = time.time()
print('stopwatch: ', finish - start)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check the right syntax of the [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). The correct way:

```
a = [x for x in range(10000) if x % 2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `if` goes after the `for x in range()`:

```
a = [x for x in range(10000) if x % 2 == 0]
```